# zxing - problems reading qr code in portrait / landscape

Tags: android, zxing

In Android Studio Emulator (Pixel 4, API30), zxing 3.5.0 recognizes qr code in portrait orientation, but not in landscape orientation. On my hardware it behaves just the opposite: landscape works OK, but not portrait. What can I do?

[portrait (recognizing qr)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhciM.png)

[landscape (not recognizing qr)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yZSR.png)

```java
    public abstract class QRCodeAnalyzer implements ImageAnalysis.Analyzer{
    @Override
    public void analyze(@NonNull ImageProxy image) {
        if (image.getFormat() == YUV_420_888 || image.getFormat() == YUV_422_888 || image.getFormat() == YUV_444_888) {
            ByteBuffer byteBuffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
            byte[] imageData = new byte[byteBuffer.capacity()];
            byteBuffer.get(imageData);
            Log.d("QR", "" + image.getImageInfo().getRotationDegrees());

            PlanarYUVLuminanceSource source = new PlanarYUVLuminanceSource(
                    imageData,
                    image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(),
                    0, 0,
                    image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(),
                    false
            );

            BinaryBitmap binaryBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));

            Map<DecodeHintType, Object> hints = new HashMap<>();
            hints.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, Boolean.TRUE);

            try {
                Result result = new QRCodeMultiReader().decode(binaryBitmap, hints);
                onQRCodeFound(result);
            } catch (FormatException | ChecksumException | NotFoundException e) {
                qrCodeNotFound();
            }
        }

        image.close();
    }

    public abstract void qrCodeNotFound();

    public abstract void onQRCodeFound(Result result);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The above code is ok, the problem is an "anvanced topic" in CameraX documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/orientation-rotation. TLDR: you have to set targetLocation of ImageAnalysis to the correct value.